# Jenkins Amazon Cloud slave can't checkout multibranch pipeline repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I configured ec2 cloud slave on jenkins - when my multibranch pipeline starting it's first checkout the scm

[image: checking out scm via shared library]

when this run on master everything works fine and the checkout success
but when it run on slave it's look it does not know the key:

[image: Jenkins console errors slave throws]

In the multibranch pipeline configurations it's configured to use my SSH credentials: 
[image: SSH Creds]

This is the key configuration: 
[image: Jenkins credentials configuration]

So it's look like the slave don't know the key - how can I configure this key in the slave ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. One hint: try to add your code as text and not as image whenever possible.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not put the private key into Jenkins home folder's `.ssh/id_rsa` etc?